# how do i enable encryption password in url on jasper server

Tags: jasperserver

I am new with jasper server, and I have to encrypt the password before giving it into url.

what I did:

1. Configure login encryption as described in Encrypting User Session 
   Login. Specify static key encryption by setting 
   encryption.dynamic.key to false and configure the keystore as described.
2. Once the server is restarted, log into the server to generate the 
   static key.
3. Open the following URL: 
   http://example.com:8080/jasperserver/encrypt.html.
   But I didn't know how to create static key on jasper server, so I skipped that step.

And now when I click on encrypt button it's not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

edit below file

> "C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2\buildomatic\conf_source\ieCe\classes\esapi\security-config.properties"

change to **encryption.on=true**